# How do I use regex extract a string but not when it contains $

Tags: regex, match

I need to extract a username direct from logs using regex but not when the username ends with $, example log below:

Username: domain\username

I've been using the following regex to extract data-`Username:.*?\\(.*?\s`

I need regex to completely ignore the string and not extract it if it ends with $

Is this possible?

Comment: provide an example along with expected output. You need to use a negative lookahead assertion.

Comment: Also please specify your language

Answer (score 1):

Search for a text and any non-$-sign at the end:

```
Username: (.*[^\$])$
```

http://regexr.com/3aail

Comment: Isn't this sufficient? `[^\$]+$`

Comment: @jurgemaister `Username: ([^\$]+)$` would not match for `Username: dom$ain\username`. Also @Jordurh wrote something about "extract data", so I suppose, that a matcher (`()`) is required.